# Does the inequality $E[X^3] \geq E[X]E[X^2]$ hold for non-negative random variable $X$?

Tags: probability, expected-value

My intuition says no, but I couldn't propose a clean counterexample:
for example, for any binary r.v. $P[X = a] = p, P[X = b] = 1 - p$ where $a, b > 0$, I found that
$$E[X^3] - E[X]E[X^2] = p(1 - p)(a + b)(a - b)^2 > 0,$$
which validates the inequality.

Could anyone give me a counterexample, or prove it (if it is indeed true)?

Comment: Why is the downvote?  It is just a conjecture so I could not show any "attempts"...

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750669)

Comment: [Proof of (a generalization of) your conjecture](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1702074)

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you, they are very helpful.